# Do I need to use strict statement for this function? It's also expecting a ':' instead of a '.' for window.onload?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Do I need to use strict statement for these functions? It's also expecting a ':' instead of a '.' for window.onload? It also says 'e' is not defined however I'm using it as an function event. Plus an unrecoverable syntax error? This is just a simple audio player for a website.

```
var audio = new Audio();
var audioPlayer = {
    albumId: 0,
    audioTrack: 0,
    currentFolder: "",
    albums: [
        {   
            artist: "Post Malone",
            album: "Beerbongs & Bentleys",
            folder: "Beerbongs & Bentleys",
            graphic: "Beerbongs & Bentleys/b&bart.png",
            songs: ["Better Now.mp3", "Psycho ft. Ty Dolla $ign.mp3", "Rockstar ft. 21 Savage.mp3"],
            songTitles: ["Better Now", "Psycho ft. Ty Dolla $ign", "Rockstar ft. 21 Savage"]
        }
    ],
    selectAlbum: function(e){
        console.log(audioPlayer.albumId);
        $("#tracks").empty();
        $("h1").text(audioPlayer.albums[audioPlayer.albumId].album);
        $("#track > span").text(audioPlayer.albums[audioPlayer.albumId].songTitles[audioPlayer.audioTrack]);
        $(".album_cover > img").attr("src", "albums/" + audioPlayer.albums[audioPlayer.albumId].graphic);
        $("#status").text("Ready to Play");
        $.each(audioPlayer.albums[audioPlayer.albumId].songTitles, function(index, item){
            $("#tracks").append("<li>" + audioPlayer.albums[audioPlayer.albumId].songTitles[index] + "</li>");
        });
    },
    playAlbum: function(){
        audio.src = "../albums/" + audioPlayer.albums[audioPlayer.albumId].folder + "/" + audioPlayer.albums[audioPlayer.albumId].songs[audioPlayer.audioTrack];
        audio.play();
    },
    changeTrack: function(direction){
        console.log(direction)
        if(direction === "forward" && audioPlayer.audioTrack < audioPlayer.albums[audioPlayer.albumId].songs.length - 1){
            audioPlayer.audioTrack++;
        }
        if(direction === "back" && audioPlayer.audioTrack < audioPlayer.albums[audioPlayer.albumId].songs.length + 1){
            audioPlayer.audioTrack--;
        }
    },

    window.onload = function(){
    audioPlayer.selectAlbum()
    $("#status").text("Playing");
}

    $(document).on("click", "#albums > div > button",
    function(e){
    var album = this.id.split("_");
    audioPlayer.albumId = parseInt(album[1]) - 1;
    audioPlayer.selectAlbum();
});
};
```

Comment: Hello :) You need to move the window.onload function and the $(document).on("click",...etc); function outside of the definition of the audioPlayer

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no need to add `"use strict"` (which generally just causes errors; see [the MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) for more details).

You're getting a syntax error because you're trying to set `window.onload` from inside an object literal. You just need to move the `};` from the last line to the line before `window.onload`.